# Android Studio: Content is not allowed in prolog when using okhttp

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, okhttp

I am developing an Android app using Android Studio 2.1.2, in which I need to use the okhttp-3.4.0-RC1 library. I put it in the assets directory and then I add it as library. When I try to run the app it gives me this error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':GeoStream:mergeDebugResources'.
> C:\Users\Beee\AndroidStudioProjects\ExoPlayer
master\GeoStream\src\main\res\Libs\okhttp-3.4.0-RC1.jar:1:1: Error: Content is
not allowed in prolog.
```

I tried to clean project and delete Gradle cache but it didn't work. How can I solve this?

Note: everything was working fine before I update Android Studio to 2.1.2.

Comment: Did you try to include the okhttp-3.4.0-RC1 as a dependency in the gradle file? compile group: 'com.squareup.okhttp3', name: 'okhttp-android-support', version: '3.4.0-RC1'

Comment: @s-hunter if that means adding the line "compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.0-RC1'" to build.gradle then yes I did it

Comment: "I put it in the assets directory" - Your error indicates that you put it in the `res` directory, not `assets`. You can't put custom directories in `res`, which is why you get that error.

Comment: You're right, it was in both res and assets. I removed the one in res but I get this error: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/maven/com.squareup.okhttp3/okhttp/pom.properties
 File1: ~\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.squareup.okhttp3\okhttp\3.4.0-RC1\979305977ca3e5e6339ba77d9bbc805e700317ca\okhttp-3.4.0-RC1.jar
 File2: ~\AndroidStudioProjects\ExoPlayer-master\GeoStream\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\ExoPlayer-master\library\unspecified\jars\classes.jar"

Comment: Oh never mind I fixed it. Apparently I had an extra line by mistake in build.gradle that adds as dependency. After that I had to update gradle plugin. Thanks much! :)